# add permissions from list of permission names

Tags: python, django

I have found a solution for adding a list of list of permission names in the format `'app_label.permission_codename'` to a group (or user, this is not important), what is the best way to do that? for now I post my answer to this question that works, but I would like to hear your solutions, and if there is a built in way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now the best solution I've come with is:

```
from itertools import izip
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, Group

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return izip(a, a)

 def get_permissions(permlist):
        pm = [{'codename':b, 'content_type__app_label': a}  for p in permlist for a, b in pairwise(p.split('.'))]
        return [Permission.objects.get(**p) for p in pm]

group = Group.objects.get(name='groupname')
group.permissions = get_permissions([
    'app1.perm_codename1',
    'app2.perm_codename2',
    'app3.perm_codename3',
    'app4.perm_codename4'])
```